# Accumulation of values based on percentage.Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have years and a percentage.
The goal is to accumulate the current percentage in the accumulation column each year.
The desired result I am looking for is in the accumulation column.

Тhis is a formula for converting percentages into numbers.
PERCENTAGE/ 100 +1

```
YEARS,          PERCENTAGE,      ACCUMULATIVE,
2010,           38.15%,           38.15%
2011,          -25.51%,           2,93%
2012,           -8.47%,           -5.80%,
2013,           18.51%,           11.64%
2014,            -2.07%,          9.32%
2015,            16.27%,          27.11%
2016,            108.94%,         165.60%
2017,            29.67%,          244.41%
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
SELECT
     YEARS,
     PERCENTAGE,
    Sum(PERCENTAGE) OVER(Order By YR ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "ACCUMULATIVE"
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        YEAR  "YEAR",
         PERCENTAGE
           
          Sum(PERCENTAGE/100+1) OVER(Partition By (YEAR ) Order By (YEAR )) "PERCENTAGE"
        FROM
          tbl
        ORDER BY
       (YEAR )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the product (multiplication) of the rows, not the sum (addition).

There is not an analytic product function; but you can calculate it by using `EXP(SUM(LN(value)))`:

```sql
SELECT YEARS,
       PERCENTAGE,
       ROUND(
         (EXP(Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)) - 1)*100,
         2
       ) AS ACCUMULATIVE
FROM   tbl
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (YEARS, PERCENTAGE) AS
SELECT 2010,  38.15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2011, -25.51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2012,  -8.47 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2013,  18.51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2014,  -2.07 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2015,  16.27 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2016, 108.94 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2017,  29.67 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | YEARS | PERCENTAGE | ACCUMULATIVE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2010 | 38.15 | 38.15 |
> | 2011 | -25.51 | 2.91 |
> | 2012 | -8.47 | -5.81 |
> | 2013 | 18.51 | 11.63 |
> | 2014 | -2.07 | 9.32 |
> | 2015 | 16.27 | 27.1 |
> | 2016 | 108.94 | 165.57 |
> | 2017 | 29.67 | 244.36 |

To get the annualized return:

```sql
SELECT YEARS,
       PERCENTAGE,
       ROUND(
         (EXP(Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)) - 1)*100,
         2
       ) AS ACCUMULATIVE,
       ROUND(
         POWER(
           EXP(Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)),
           1/COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Years)
         ) * 100 - 100,
         2
       ) AS annualized_return
FROM   tbl
```

Which outputs:

> | YEARS | PERCENTAGE | ACCUMULATIVE | ANNUALIZED_RETURN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2010 | 38.15 | 38.15 | 38.15 |
> | 2011 | -25.51 | 2.91 | 1.44 |
> | 2012 | -8.47 | -5.81 | -1.97 |
> | 2013 | 18.51 | 11.63 | 2.79 |
> | 2014 | -2.07 | 9.32 | 1.8 |
> | 2015 | 16.27 | 27.1 | 4.08 |
> | 2016 | 108.94 | 165.57 | 14.97 |
> | 2017 | 29.67 | 244.36 | 16.71 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0bdceebdce3d95fd48c6ede90e1b7ba0)*

Comment: Thanks for how I can calculate the total of the accumulative

Comment: @МариянЦветков Take the value of the final row? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "total".

Comment: Тhe total  result of this column ACCUMULATIVE  is 16.87.  but I'm not sure how I could get it“

Comment: @МариянЦветков What calculation did you perform to get 16.87?

Comment: Annualized  return calculation to most recent accumulative PERCENTAGE.

Comment: @МариянЦветков Please can you explain what that means? What is the calculation necessary to calculate that value?

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks for the post and effort.

Comment: @МариянЦветков Managed to find a formula for it and have updated the answer.