# Getting the first and last result Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Based on this query is it possible to take the first and last result of the year and annualized_return.

```
CREATE TABLE t (YEARS, PERCENTAGE) AS
SELECT 2014,  38.15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2015, -25.51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2016,  -8.47 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2017,  18.51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2018,  -2.07 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2019,  16.27 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  108.94 FROM DUAL UNION ALL

SELECT 2021,  29.67 FROM DUAL
```

in this select how can i take the first row (result) from YEARS  2014
and
annualized_return 16.71

```
SELECT YEARS,
       PERCENTAGE,
       ROUND(
         (EXP(Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)) - 1)*100,
         2
       ) AS ACCUMULATIVE,
       
       
       
       ROUND(
         POWER(
           EXP(Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)),1/COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Years)) * 100 - 100,2) AS annualized_return
FROM   tbl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the first and last rows based on years then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function with [my original query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535541/1509264) to filter for the row with the earliest and latest year:

```sql
SELECT years, percentage, annualized_return
FROM   (
  SELECT YEARS,
         PERCENTAGE,
         ROUND(
           (EXP(Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)) - 1)*100,
           2
         ) AS ACCUMULATIVE,
         ROUND(
           POWER(
             EXP(
               Sum(LN(1 + PERCENTAGE/100)) OVER(Order By Years)
             ),
             1/COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Years)
           ) * 100 - 100,
           2
         ) AS annualized_return,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Years ASC ) AS rn_asc,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Years DESC) AS rn_desc
  FROM   t
)
WHERE  rn_asc  = 1
OR     rn_desc = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | YEARS | PERCENTAGE | ANNUALIZED_RETURN |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021 | 29.67 | 16.71 |
> | 2014 | 38.15 | 38.15 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28df42d9726f3d202113f4e653b85b17)*